# Rust + rocket: Return file using `NamedFile` gives wrong file extension

Tags: rust, download, xlsx, rust-rocket

Using `xlsxwriter`, I have created an .xlsx file ( `fn create_workbook()`) that I want to send to the client using `rocket`. Downloading works, but the extension is wrong. Ideally, the file should be deleted after the client has downloaded it.

Creating the file works (it's stored under `target/simple1.xlsx`), however, the file that gets downloaded upon visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000
is a `.dms` file rather than a `.xlsx` file. Apparently, the problem is only the file name (and hence, also the extension): If one changes the extension of the downloaded file to `.xlsx`, it is the desired document.

Also, I don't know how to delete the file after it has been downloaded from the server, since the function will be exited right after it has been downloaded. (I'm new to rust and also happy about any code recommendations)

```
use std::fs;
use std::path;
use rocket::{
    response::status::NotFound,
    fs::{FileServer,
         NamedFile}
};
use xlsxwriter::Workbook;

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

// create an xlsx workbook at "target/simple1.xlsx"
fn create_workbook()->Result<Vec<u8>,xlsxwriter::XlsxError>{
    let workbook = Workbook::new("target/simple1.xlsx");
    let mut sheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet(None)?;
    sheet1.write_string(2,1,"Hello, world!",None)?;
    workbook.close().expect("workbook can be closed");
    let result = fs::read("target/simple1.xlsx").expect("can read file");
    Ok(result)
}


#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> NamedFile  {
    let file = create_workbook().expect("file can be created");
    let path_to_file = path::Path::new("target/simple1.xlsx");
    let res = NamedFile::open(&path_to_file).await.map_err(|e| NotFound(e.to_string()));
    match res {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => panic!("Problem with file {:?}", error),
    }
    // ideally, the file would be deleted after it has been sent to the client
    // fs::remove_file("target/simple1.xlsx").expect("can delete file");
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let rocket= rocket::build();
    rocket
        .mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

The `Cargo.toml` file is:

```
[package]
name = "demo_download_xlsx_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
xlsxwriter = "0.4.0"

[dependencies.rocket]
version = "0.5.0-rc.2"
```

I followed the `Response` guide as closely as possible ([doc](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/responses/#rocket-responders)). I also tried returning a `Result<NamedFile, NotFound<String>>`.

Comment: Would you mind posting a new question for deleting a file after responding? I think such a question would be valuable to future readers on its own (and questions should focus on one thing at a time anyway :) )

Comment: Sure, that makes sense -- may I reuse your code for the MWE in that new question? (The code in my question is shorter, hence more 'minimal', but not entirely 'working' with the extension and filename flaw, so it might make more sense to post the question with your code...)

Comment: Absolutely! You can link back to this question if it builds off the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the documentation for how [`NamedFile`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/fs/struct.NamedFile.html) implements `Responder`, we find:

> Streams the named file to the client. Sets or overrides the Content-Type in the response according to the file’s extension if the extension is recognized. See `ContentType::from_extension()` for more information. If you would like to stream a file with a different Content-Type than that implied by its extension, use a `File` directly.

And looking at [`ContentType::from_extension()`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/http/struct.ContentType.html#method.from_extension) it does not recognize ".xlsx" as a known extension. So it does not set a proper content-type header and thus your computer tries its best to figure out the file type without it; I'm guessing ".dms" files have some structural similarity to ".xlsx" files.

From this question, [What is a correct MIME type for .docx, .pptx, etc.?](/q/4212861/2189130), the content-type should be `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`. You can set a specific content-type using [`ContentType`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/http/struct.ContentType.html) alongside your file like so:

```
#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> (ContentType, NamedFile) {
    // ... create the file ...

    let content_type = ContentType::new("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    let file = NamedFile::open("target/simple1.xlsx").await.unwrap();

    (content_type, file)
}
```

This will now indicate to your browser that it is an ".xlsx" file and should save it as such.

---

I'll follow up by mentioning that while the *extension* now matches what is expected, the *name* of the file is still left up to the browser's discretion (often either a random name or one based on the route). If you want to be able to set the file name as well, you need to return a [content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header. Unfortunately, there's not a quick-and-handy Rocket type for that, so you'd have to implement it yourself.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

use rocket::response::{Responder, Result};
use rocket::Request;

pub struct NamedXlsxFile {
    name: PathBuf,
    file: File,
}

impl NamedXlsxFile {
    pub fn new(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> NamedXlsxFile {
        // TODO: error propagation

        let path = path.as_ref();
        let name = path.file_name().unwrap().into();
        let file = File::open(path).unwrap();

        NamedXlsxFile { name, file }
    }
}

impl<'r> Responder<'r, 'static> for NamedXlsxFile {
    fn respond_to(self, request: &'r Request<'_>) -> Result<'static> {
        use rocket::http::hyper::header::*;

        let content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        let content_disposition = format!("attachment; filename=\"{}\"", self.name.display());

        let mut response = self.file.respond_to(request)?;
        response.set_raw_header(CONTENT_TYPE.as_str(), content_type);
        response.set_raw_header(CONTENT_DISPOSITION.as_str(), content_disposition);

        Ok(response)
    }
}
```

```
#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> NamedXlsxFile {
    // ... create the file ...

    let file = create_workbook().expect("file can be created");
    let file = NamedXlsxFile::new("target/simple1.xlsx");

    file
}
```